# Powershell IP address range

Tags: powershell, ip

I need to help with my code which is write in Powershell. Program should generate IP addresses in range. For example from 10.4.254.250 to 10.4.255.255.

When I have the same subnet (from 10.4.255.x to 10.4.255.x), all is correct. Problem starts when I have different subnet (from 10.4.254.250 to 10.4.255.255).

Output is invalid. Try it please. Thank you, for your help.

Correct output should be, that ip address which is 10.4.255.X starts from 1. Now starts from 250 to 255.

I need to get all ip addresses from variable $from to variable $to. When IP address in the same subnet $from = "10.4.255.1" $to = "10.4.255.1" all is correct. Problem starts, when different subnet $from = "10.4.254.250" $to = "10.4.255.255"

Look at my code bellow:

```
$from = "10.4.254.250"
$to = "10.4.255.255"

$Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
$Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."

foreach ($Ip_Adresa_A in $Ip_Adresa_Od[0]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[0])
{
    foreach ($Ip_Adresa_B in $Ip_Adresa_Od[1]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[1])
    {
        foreach ($Ip_Adresa_C in $Ip_Adresa_Od[2]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[2])
        {
            foreach ($Ip_Adresa_D in $Ip_Adresa_Od[3]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[3])
            {
                $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace = "$Ip_Adresa_A.$Ip_Adresa_B.$Ip_Adresa_C.$Ip_Adresa_D"
                $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wrong output is:

```
10.4.254.250
10.4.254.251
10.4.254.252
10.4.254.253
10.4.254.254
10.4.254.255
10.4.255.250
10.4.255.251
10.4.255.252
10.4.255.253
10.4.255.254
10.4.255.255
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with an example of the output you are getting and the output you want?

Comment: Done, I have added update.

Comment: Hint: there is no logic to handle starting from .1 when the addresses are from different subnets.

Comment: @vonPryz Can I ask you if you can give me some hint, or piece of code, that solve my problem?

Comment: In this specific instance, it may be interesting to step back and explain what you want to achieve. There may be better solutions to your problem.

Comment: @GabQ I need to get all ip adresses from varible $from to variable $to. When IP adress in the same subnet $from = "10.4.255.1" $to = "10.4.255.1" all is correct. Problem starts, when different subnet $from = "10.4.254.250" $to = "10.4.255.255" btw i have update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your IP address to an integer and then in each iteration of a for loop convert the integer to a byte array:

```
$from = "10.4.254.250"
$to = "10.4.255.255"

$Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
$Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."

#change endianness
[array]::Reverse($Ip_Adresa_Od)
[array]::Reverse($Ip_Adresa_Do)

#convert octets to integer
$start=[bitconverter]::ToUInt32([byte[]]$Ip_Adresa_Od,0)
$end=[bitconverter]::ToUInt32([byte[]]$Ip_Adresa_Do,0)

for ($ip=$start; $ip -lt $end; $ip++)
{ 
    #convert integer back to byte array
    $get_ip=[bitconverter]::getbytes($ip)

    #change endianness
    [array]::Reverse($get_ip)

    $new_ip=$get_ip -join "."
    $new_ip
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask you, if I can use foreach with parallel parameter? It will be very helpfull, becouse our ranges are very big and programs running about 8 hours. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Working with IP addresses and ranges is complicated, and something I try to avoid if a program/software I am using does it already. Here are some functions that I wrote a while back that convert the addresses to decimal values, that are easier to manipulate. There are probably better, more precise solutions than this, but it will also return a range based off an address with a Subnet address or CIDR mask too. It should also cover the case [@vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) mentioned where the addresses are across `.24` CIDR ranges.

```
function Find-IPRange {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Determines all the IP address in a given range or subnet.
    .DESCRIPTION
    This function can evaluate a set of addresses based of the following three options:

        Range - What IP addresses are between this and that address
        Mask - What are the IP addresses given a particular IP address and mask, i.e. 24, 25.
        Subnet - What are the IP addresses given a particular IP address and subnet address, i.e 255.255.0.0, 255.255.255.192

    You have to specify an IP address to use the subnet and mask options. For the range you have to specify two addresses.
    .PARAMETER Start
    Start address of an IP range
    .PARAMETER End
    End address of an IP range
    .PARAMETER IP
    Any valid ip address
    .PARAMETER Subnet
    A valid Subnet IP address i.e. 255.255.255.0, 255.255.0.0
    .PARAMETER Mask
    A valid net mask from 0 to 32
    .EXAMPLE
    Find-IPRange -IP 192.168.0.4 -mask 30
    .EXAMPLE
    Find-IPRange -Start 192.168.1.250 -End 192.168.2.5
    .EXAMPLE
    Find-IPRange -IP 10.100.100.10 -Subnet 255.255.255.240
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Range")]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Range")]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]
        $Start,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Range")]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]
        $End,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Mask")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Subnet")]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]
        $IP,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Subnet")]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]
        $Subnet,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Mask")]
        [ValidateRange(0, 32)]
        [System.Int32]
        $Mask,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Mask")]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Subnet")]
        [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
        $ReturnRange
    )
    Begin {
        # If the user specifies a mask, then convert it to a subnet ip address
        if ($Mask) {
            $Binary = ("1" * $Mask) + ("0" * (32 - $Mask))
            $Decimal = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($Binary, 2)
            [System.Net.IPAddress]$Subnet = ConvertFrom-IntToIP -Decimal $Decimal
        }
    }
    Process {
        # If we're looking at a subnet, we need to establish the start address and the broadcast address for it. We're using bitwise operators to do this.
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ne "Range") {
            # Compare bits where both are a match using the bitwise AND operator
            [System.Net.IPAddress]$SubnetAddr = $Subnet.Address -band $IP.Address

            # Flip the subnet mask i.e. 0.0.0.255 for 255.255.255.0 by using the bitwise XOR operator and then compare against a bitwise OR operator
            [System.Net.IPAddress]$Broadcast = ([System.Net.IPAddress]'255.255.255.255').Address -bxor $Subnet.Address -bor $SubnetAddr.Address

            # Return the start and end of a subnet only if requested
            if ($ReturnRange) { return $SubnetAddr, $Broadcast }

            # Convert the start and end of the ranges to integers
            $RangeStart = ConvertFrom-IPToInt -ip $SubnetAddr.IPAddressToString
            $RangeEnd = ConvertFrom-IPToInt -ip $Broadcast.IPAddressToString
        }
        else {
            $RangeStart = ConvertFrom-IPToInt -ip $Start.IPAddressToString
            $RangeEnd = ConvertFrom-IPToInt -ip $End.IPAddressToString
        }

        # Loop through the points between the start and end of the ranges and convert them back to IP addresses
        for ($Addr = $RangeStart; $Addr -le $RangeEnd; $Addr ++) { ConvertFrom-IntToIP -Decimal $Addr }
    }
    End {
    }
}

function ConvertFrom-IPToInt {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Converts an IP address to an Int64 value.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Converts an IP address to an Int64 value.
    .PARAMETER IP
    A valid IP address to be converted to an integer
    .EXAMPLE
    ConvertFrom-IPToInt -IP 192.168.0.1
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]
        $IP
    )
    Begin {
    }
    Process {
        # Split the IP address in to octets
        $Octets = $IP -split "\."

        # Multiply the octets based on the maximum number of addresses each octet provides.
        [System.Int64]$Decimal = ([System.Int32]$Octets[0] * [System.Math]::Pow(256, 3)) +
            ([System.Int32]$Octets[1] * [System.Math]::Pow(256, 2)) +
            ([System.Int32]$Octets[2] * 256) +
            ([System.Int32]$Octets[3])
    }
    End {
        # Return the int64 value
        $Decimal
    }
}

function ConvertFrom-IntToIP {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Converts an Int64 value to an IP address.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Converts an Int64 value to an IP address.
    .PARAMETER Decimal
    A decimal value for the IP Address to be converted
    .EXAMPLE
    ConvertFrom-IntToIP -Decimal 3232235521
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Int64]
        $Decimal
    )
    Begin {
        # Initialise an array for the octets
        $Octets = @()
    }
    Process {
        # Work out first octet by dividing by the total number of addresses.
        $Octets += [System.String]([System.Math]::Truncate($Decimal / [System.Math]::Pow(256, 3)))

        # Work out second octet by the modulus of the first octets total number of addresses divided by the total number of address available for a class B subnet.
        $Octets += [System.String]([System.Math]::Truncate(($Decimal % [System.Math]::Pow(256, 3)) / [System.Math]::Pow(256, 2)))

        # Work out third octet by the modulus of the second octets total number of addresses divided by the total number of address available for a class C subnet.
        $Octets += [System.String]([System.Math]::Truncate(($Decimal % [System.Math]::Pow(256, 2)) / 256))

        # Work out fourth octet by the modulus of the third octets total number of addresses.
        $Octets += [System.String]([System.Math]::Truncate($Decimal % 256))

        # Join the strings to form the IP address
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$IP = $Octets -join "."
    }
    End {
        # Return the ip address object
        $IP.IPAddressToString
    }
}
```

<sup>**DISCLAIMER:** I am not a network engineer so please feel free to suggest any changes to how the addresses are converted to ints and back. This function also hasn't been through any unit testing, so there may be cases that exist where it does not work.</sup>

Example Output:

```
Find-IPRange -Start 10.4.254.250 -End 10.4.255.255
10.4.254.250
10.4.254.251
10.4.254.252
10.4.254.253
10.4.254.254
10.4.254.255
10.4.255.0
10.4.255.1
10.4.255.2
...truncated
10.4.255.249
10.4.255.250
10.4.255.251
10.4.255.252
10.4.255.253
10.4.255.254
10.4.255.255
```

Other uses:

```
Find-IPRange -IP 192.168.0.4 -Mask 28
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.13
192.168.0.14
192.168.0.15

Find-IPRange -IP 192.168.0.4 -Subnet 255.255.255.252
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

> I hope I understand your question. I believe you would like to restart the counter on the 4th octet back to 1 once the 3rd octet iterates from 254 to 255? There's probably a better way to do this but for now hopefully this works. I've added an if statement that resets the range once the final 10.4.254.255 ip is reached. This will allow your loop to include the 10.4.255.x range starting from 1 in the 4th octet until 255 is reached. The while loop condition will be set to false once the final 10.4.255.255 IP is reached and exit.
> I hope this helps and provides the desired result.

```
$from = "10.4.254.250"
$to = "10.4.254.255"

$Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
$Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."
$run = "true";

while($run -eq "true")
{

   if($Ip_Adresa_Pocitace -eq "10.4.254.255")
   {
    
            $from = "10.4.255.1"
            $to = "10.4.255.255"

            $Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
            $Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."

    }

    foreach ($Ip_Adresa_C in $Ip_Adresa_Od[2]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[2])
    {
        foreach ($Ip_Adresa_D in $Ip_Adresa_Od[3]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[3])
        {
            $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace = "10.4.$Ip_Adresa_C.$Ip_Adresa_D"
            $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace
   
            if($Ip_Adresa_Pocitace -eq "10.4.255.255")
            {
                $run = "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Results:
> 10.4.254.250
> 10.4.254.251
> 10.4.254.252
> 10.4.254.253
> 10.4.254.254
> 10.4.254.255
> 10.4.255.1
> 10.4.255.2
> 10.4.255.3
> ...
> 10.4.255.249
> 10.4.255.250
> 10.4.255.251
> 10.4.255.252
> 10.4.255.253
> 10.4.255.254
> 10.4.255.255
>
> Solution w/ new parameters.

```
# Orininal Parameters
# $from = "10.4.254.250"
# $to = "10.4.254.255"
$from = "10.4.253.250" 
$to = "10.4.253.255"

$Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
$Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."
$run = "true";

while($run -eq "true")
{

   if($Ip_Adresa_Pocitace -eq "10.4.253.255")
   {
         # Orininal Parameters   
         #   $from = "10.4.255.1"
         #  $to = "10.4.255.255"

         $from = "10.4.254.1" 
         $to = "10.4.254.255"
          $end = $to
            $Ip_Adresa_Od = $from -split "\."
            $Ip_Adresa_Do = $to -split "\."

    }

    foreach ($Ip_Adresa_C in $Ip_Adresa_Od[2]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[2])
    {
        foreach ($Ip_Adresa_D in $Ip_Adresa_Od[3]..$Ip_Adresa_Do[3])
        {
            $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace = "10.4.$Ip_Adresa_C.$Ip_Adresa_D"
            $Ip_Adresa_Pocitace
   
            if($Ip_Adresa_Pocitace -eq $end)
            {
                $run = "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Results:
> 10.4.253.250
> 10.4.253.251
> 10.4.253.252
> 10.4.253.253
> 10.4.253.254
> 10.4.253.255
> 10.4.254.1
> 10.4.254.2
> 10.4.254.3
> ...
> 10.4.254.253
> 10.4.254.254
> 10.4.254.255

Comment: Thank you, but your code does not works in range between $from = "10.4.253.250"
$to = "10.4.254.255"

Comment: Sure it will just update the parameters in the code!!! :)                                                    Solution was based on original/provided code base with example parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The binary method is much faster, '[FastPing](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FastPing/0.6.0)' is a solid example. See 'GetNetworkRange' (requires ConvertToNetwork & ConvertToDeicmal from script). You can copy those 3 functions into an ISE session to play with it.

I wrote a string method to generate lists and I believe it is accurate (hoping for feedback - Module [Test-PowerPing](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-PowerPing/1.2.0.0)). The address generation method is 'Get-PowerIPRange'.

I'm working to get comments added, but loop complexity would vary depending on differences in start/end octets 'a.b.c.d'. If no changes in start/end a.b.c (all equal), you're only modifying final octet, 'd' (max 256 address):

```
$range = 0..255
$range | foreach-object {'a.b.c.'+"$_"}
```

If difference in third octet, 'c', loop complexity would increase. The logic above would be applied for each change in 'c'. You could loop as needed, and I chose to use an arraylist to manage the list for additions, etc.

```
$range = 0..255
$base = 'a.b.' + '0'
$range | foreach-object {$base+ ".$_"}
$base = 'a.b.' + '1'
$range | foreach-object {$base+ ".$_"}
```

But to have something you can just use, you have to account for various start/end scenarios. We can't just 0..255 for every range, and we need to add logic to jump from loops modifying 'c' & 'd' to modifying just 'd' for final entries, etc.